# WinForms DataGridView read from XML - can't filter on Date because it doesn't realize an attribute is a DateTime?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to be able to filter a DataGridView based on DateTime information (earlier than or greater than a certain date), but when I create the filter it says that it can't compare strings to DateTimes, because it reads all the information from an XML file as strings and I have no idea how to type them. **Can anyone help?**

**More detailed explanation:** I have an XML file full of information that I pull into a DataSet with `myDataSet.ReadXML()`. I create the XML myself in an earlier step. Here's a sample:

```
<site>
<subsite URL="http://website/home">
    <pages />
    <subsite URL="http://website/home/de-de">
        <pages>
            <page name="default_ex.xml" URL="http://www.my-website.com/home/de-de/default_ex.aspx" CreatedOn="8/23/2012 3:13:47 PM" CreatedBy="Joe Schmoe" LastModifiedOn="8/23/2012 3:17:44 PM" LastModifiedBy="Joe Schmoe" Version="1.0" PublishingStartDate="" PublishingExpirationDate="" ApprovalState="APPROVED" FileSize="1120" CheckedOutUser="" DaysSinceCreated="46" DaysSinceLastModified="46" IsPublicFacing="False"/>
        </pages>
    </subsite>
    <subsite URL="http://website/home/en-us">
        <pages>
            <page name="default_ex.xml" URL="http://www.my-website.com/home/en-us/default_ex.aspx" CreatedOn="8/23/2012 10:40:53 AM" CreatedBy="Joe Schmoe" LastModifiedOn="8/23/2012 2:55:15 PM" LastModifiedBy="Joe Schmoe" Version="2.0" PublishingStartDate="" PublishingExpirationDate="" ApprovalState="APPROVED" FileSize="1122" CheckedOutUser="" DaysSinceCreated="46" DaysSinceLastModified="46" IsPublicFacing="False"/>
        </pages>
    </subsite>
    <subsite URL="http://website/home/fr-fr">
        <pages>
            <page name="default_ex.xml" URL="http://www.my-website.com/home/fr-fr/default_ex.aspx" CreatedOn="8/2012 1:12:30 PM" CreatedBy="Boring Guy" LastModifiedOn="8/23/2012 11:59:41 AM" LastModifiedBy="Joe Schmoe" Version="1.1" PublishingStartDate="" PublishingExpirationDate="" ApprovalState="PENDING" FileSize="955" CheckedOutUser="" DaysSinceCreated="47" DaysSinceLastModified="46" IsPublicFacing="False"/>
        </pages>
    </subsite>
    <subsite URL="http://website/home/ja-jp">
        <pages>
            <page name="default_ex.xml" URL="http://www.my-website.com/home/ja-jp/default_ex.aspx" CreatedOn="8/23/2012 3:50:29 PM" CreatedBy="Mary Poppins" LastModifiedOn="8/23/2012 3:58:28 PM" LastModifiedBy="Mary Poppins" Version="1.0" PublishingStartDate="" PublishingExpirationDate="" ApprovalState="APPROVED" FileSize="1199" CheckedOutUser="" DaysSinceCreated="46" DaysSinceLastModified="46" IsPublicFacing="False"/>
        </pages>
    </subsite>
</subsite>
```

...then load it up into a DataGridView like so...:

```
myDataSet.ReadXml(@"MyData.xml");
myDataView = new DataView(myDataSet.Tables["Page"]);
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataView;
```

...works great so far. I can even filter it pretty easily, but when I try to do some filtering based on attributes that aren't meant to be strings (say, "LastModifiedOn"), like so...:

```
myDataView.RowFilter = "PublishingExpirationDate > #" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString() + "#";
```

...I get an error, because as far as the DataView (or DataGridView, I'm not sure) is concerned, "PublishingExpirationDate"s are strings. **How can I have the ability to filter based on non-string columns?**

*NOTE: I'm a little new to XML, and I create the XML myself in this project in an earlier step, so I can modify the syntax if that's required to make this work, I just don't know how.*

Please and thanks!
 - Keith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've identified the problem:  the 'PublishingExpirationDate' field in your XML file is being represented as a string and not a `System.DateTime` so your `DateTime` comparison is failing.

One solution is to specify the data type of that particular field to a `DateTime` when the XML is created.

Another option is to set the [`DataColumn.Expression` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx#Y5077) to use the `Convert` function.  If you try this however you'll find it fails on the records that have empty values in the 'PublishingExpirationDate' field.  To get around this use the `IIf` function to determine if this field is empty for a given record and if it is substitute an arbitrary `DateTime` value that will get the results you want from your comparison.

It appears your `RowFilter` is excluding records with 'PublishingExpirationDate' dates in the past.  In this case you might substitute `DateTime.Min` for comparison dates for records that have empty 'PublishingExpirationDate' field values.

Here's here's what your filter might look like:

```
var filter = string.Format("CONVERT(IIF(LEN(PublishingExpirationDate) = 0,'{0}',PublishingExpirationDate),'System.DateTime') > #{1}#", DateTime.MinValue.ToString(), DateTime.Today.ToString());
myDataView.RowFilter = filter;
```

Comment: Fantasic! Works like a charm. Thanks Jay